# Cannot set style-display of a div containing another component through a component in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typeerror

I am aiming to create a component containing a function, in which a button removes a separate div containing text, which is presented in React.js by another component in a separate div.

Below is the code for my app.js. I would like to set the style of "tweetSection" to "none" (contains Tweet component that provides the text), using the "TurnOff" component.

````
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Tweet from './Tweet';
import TurnOff from './TurnOff';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <div id="tweetSection">

    <Tweet />
    </div>
    <div id="button">
    <TurnOff />

    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Here is the code for my TurnOff component

```
import React from 'react';

function TurnOff(){
  const toggle = () => {
    document.getElementById('tweetSection').style.display = "none";



  }



  return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={toggle()}>this is a button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TurnOff;
```

When I run this, I get a type error stating "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null". Is there a simplistic way, or program this in a different manner in order to hide the "tweetSection" div?

Comment: You probably don't need the extra div elements with IDs. It is generally a bad design if you are getting elements by id, this is not the react way. Use the useState hook to store the visibility, and set the style prop directly on the Tweet component using the state variable. The button's click handler can manipulate the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things.

To answer why you are getting the error, it is because you are calling the function (`toggle()`) immeaditely with `onClick={toggle()}`.

Use this to avoid the problem of calling the function too early:

```
    <button onClick={toggle}>this is a button</button>
```

Or:

```
    <button onClick={() => toggle()}>this is a button</button>
```

It is being called as soon as it renders, which means `document.getElementById('tweetSection')` might be null.

You can check for this like:

```
const el = document.getElementById('tweetSection');
if (el) {
  el.style.display = "none";
} else {
  console.warn('No tweetSection element found');
}
```

However, a more react way to solve this problem would be to pass props:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Tweet from './Tweet';
import TurnOff from './TurnOff';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [showTweet, setShowTweet] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
     {showTweet && <div id="tweetSection">
      <Tweet />
     </div>}
    <div id="button">
       <TurnOff toggle={() => {
          setShowTweet(!showTweet);
        }}
       />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

function TurnOff({ toggle }){
  return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={toggle}>this is a button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TurnOff;
```